# before_script curl download fails to write font file on Travis CI

Tags: curl, testing, fonts, download, travis-ci

I'm hitting a roadblock as I'm downloading a font to test my app. However, writing the file to the disk fail due to some obscure reason.

```
$ bash ./test/fetch-fonts.bash
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   176  100   176    0     0    526      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   533
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: ./resources/fonts/DroidSansFallbackFull.ttf: No such file or 
Warning: directory
0 3938k    0  1925    0     0   4737      0  0:14:11 --:--:--  0:14:11  4737
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1925)
The command "bash ./test/fetch-fonts.bash" failed and exited with 23 during .
```

#### Update

I tried with a smaller font (104Kb instead of 3.8Mb) and got the same behavior .

#### Question

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@BanzaiMan](https://github.com/BanzaiMan) on [the github issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7560)

> I think you need to **create the directory ./resources/fonts** so that `curl` can write to it.